# Return Taxonomy Name for Each Term

Tags: taxonomy, terms

I am returning a list of the terms from three different taxonomies.

```
$terms = get_terms(array("air-categories","web-categories","ink-categories"));
```

I get the list and I need each to link to a different section of my site based on what taxonomy they are in but I can't seem to think of a way to return an if statement for which taxonomy each term is in.

```
global $post;
$published_posts = wp_count_posts()->publish;
$terms = get_terms(array("air-categories","web-categories","ink-categories"));
    $count = count($terms);
    if ( $count > 0 ){
        echo "<ul>";
        foreach ( $terms as $term )             {
            $c = $term->count;
            $term_percent = log($c)*5;
                                                    echo "<li><a href='";
        if( ***would like to check for the taxonomy here*** ) {
              echo "***and then change the link here based on the result***";
         }
        echo "'><span class='label'>" . $term->name . "</span><span class='bar' style='width:".$term_percent."%;'></span><span class='count'>". $term->count ."</span></a></li>";
        }
        echo "</ul>";
                                                 }
    wp_reset_query();
```

Answer (score 2):

`$term->taxonomy` is the taxonomy name for each term, `$term->term_taxonomy_id` the – wait for it! – taxonomy ID.

To get the display names use `get_taxonomy()`:

```
$terms = get_terms( array( 'category', 'post_tag' ) );

foreach ( $terms as $term )
{
    $tax_name = esc_html( get_taxonomy( $term->taxonomy )->labels->name );
    echo "$term->name ($tax_name)<br>";
}
```

Comment: thank you very much. i think part of my problem for most of the time is that i wasnt working inside that foreach loop when trying to get the taxonomy name.